# Is it possible to force or find out the native resolution on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

One of the core features in our Unity Android app requires us to be able to figure out what the native resolution of any given device is. Unfortunately the resolution our app runs at seems to be inconsistent, sometimes running at native and sometimes running at less than native resolution. This will vary between builds with little to no actual changes between them.

`Screen.currentResolution` only returns the app's resolution, and the same goes for `Display.systemWidth` and `Display.systemHeight`. 
I've also tried requesting the display width and height using the following code (using AndroidJNI):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

But it appears this also only returns the app resolution, and not display resolution.

Is there any way to force Unity to run in native resolution, or otherwise figure out what the native resolution is?

Comment: I always thought that `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` return the app's resolution while `Screen.currentResolution` returns the displays resolution ... oh but I guess only in windowed mode: `If the player is running in window mode, this returns the current resolution of the desktop.`

Comment: `Is there any way to force Unity to run in native resolution` wouldn't run in [fullscreen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-fullScreen.html) mode solve this?

Comment: @derHugo On Android, `Screen.fullScreen` only toggles whether the navigation bar shows on screen or not. And `Screen.currentResolution` returns the app's resolution, not device / screen resolution.